# SuiteScript 2.0 Retrieve a Role's Permission Level for a specific Custom Record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Within an SS2.0 BeforeLoad script, I'm trying to retrieve the current user/role permission level for a specific record.

The custom record name is `customrecord_payments` with an internal id of 368.

Using the following:

```
var permission = runtime.getCurrentUser().getPermission({name:'LIST_CUSTRECORDENTRY368'})
```

Always returns a value of 4 ("FULL") regardless of the user role logged in, so the code above cannot be correct.

What is the correct "permission" to look up?

Answer (score 2):

name:'LIST_CUSTRECORDENTRY368' this would be different for different accounts.
I have retrieved that id by creating a search of  type: 'customrecordtype' and then comparing the scriptId , to get the id and then appending it to LIST_CUSTRECORDENTRY. and then getting the permission using getpermission api.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot access the specific permissions of a record, only the permissions that are available on the employee record, which pertain to records as a whole. To get around this, you'll need to maintain the logic in your record as well as the code. So it would be something like:

```js
if ((user.role === role.id) && (context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT)) {
  // ...
}
```

If you find out otherwise, please let us know!